# Delete a Realm model with Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I need to remove old, empty models from a Realm Cocoa database.

There seems to be [a way to do it in Java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1382#issuecomment-205333334), but not in Swift. Is that correct?

If you remove a property and initiate a migration Realm will remove the corresponding column in the table:

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  // dynamic var age = 0
}
```

But, if you remove the model definition entirely, the migration does **not** remove the table:

```
// class Dog: Object {
//   dynamic var name = ""
//   dynamic var age = 0
// }
```

Here's a screenshot from Realm Browser showing the empty tables I want to delete:

[image: realm browser empty tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`Migration.deleteData(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration10deleteDataFSSSb) within your migration block to specify that the named class should be completely removed from your Realm file.

Comment: Thanks! That worked well. Also, if anyone else finds this, don't forget to also remove your model definitions. Otherwise, you'll still end up with empty tables even after calling Migration.deleteData(_:).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working on JavaScript:

```
migration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {
  if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < *version*) {
    newRealm.deleteModel('MODEL-NAME')
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.