# "Phantom classes/Models" still appearing in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift4

I'm going mental trying to work this out.  I had 2 old classes which are no longer used in my code.

I'm trying to get rid of them in my Realm.  I have tried a migration and a delete and restart and they just keep coming back (they don't have any objects in but it's untidy and annoying!)

I've tried this :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 2,

        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {

                migration.deleteData(forType: "Exercise")
                migration.deleteData(forType: "Workout")
            }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    let realm = try! Realm()
```

and I've also tried this :

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
```

One of the classes is called "Workout" and I've got a Struct called "Workout" elsewhere in code but it hasn't even got the same fields etc.

**Research** I'm sure I've tried what others have in [Delete a Realm model with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407452/delete-a-realm-model-with-swift) , https://www.realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations and here [How to delete a class from realm file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717796/how-to-delete-a-class-from-realm-file)

Any ideas?  I've done a CMD+SHIFT+F and the old classes definitely aren't in my code so I'm guessing I'm not doing migration correctly?

**Update for those having same issue**

I deleted the file completely using the details here [How to completely remove Realm database from iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396319/how-to-completely-remove-realm-database-from-ios)

I'm not sure what I did wrong though!

Comment: Are you using Realm Sync?

Comment: no just regular realm

Comment: You shouldn't even have a manual migration block for this type of migration, `Realm` can handle the deletion of `Object` subclasses on its own. Moreover, are you sure that these classes only existed in `schemaVersion` 0 and not in `schemaVersion` 1?

Comment: I deleted them before I even tried the migration block.  I don't know if it's causing the issue but I actually deleted the whole file they were (a separate swift file) before migrating anything.  They are just stuck there